# text message disapears after doing javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form and I'm doing some validation JavaScript before send it to PHP, and the JavaScript function after validation post the text the user entered in a `<p>` tag at the bottom of the page; However, this message displays briefly and then disappears...

How can I make the message stay in the page, and send the rest of data to a PHP script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Contact Us</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- stylesheet for this form -->
    <link href="contact-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm() {
            var message = "";
            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;        

            var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
            var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
            var subject = document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;
            var text = document.forms["myForm"]["text"].value;
            var outputMsg = "";

            if (name == null || name == "") {               
                message += "name field missing!\n";
            }               
            if (name != "" && !name.match(letters)) {
                message += "Invalid name: only letters allowed!\n";
            }
            if (subject == null || subject == "") {
                message += "Subject field is empty!\n";
            }
            if (text == null || text == "") {
                message += "Text field is empty!\n";
            }           

            if (message != "" ) {
                alert(message);
                return false;
            }

            outputMsg = "Message Sent!....\n" + 
                        "Name: " + name + "\n" +
                        "Email: " + email + "\n" + 
                        "Subject: " + subject + "\n" +
                        "Text: " + text + "\n";

            document.getElementById("msg-result").innerHTML = outputMsg;
            return true;

        }    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="hero-unit" style="padding:20px 100px">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <p>aldkfjasdkfjaskdfasdfkasdkfjadsfjsdkfjaskfjasdkfjasjfaskdfjsdkfjsksdsdkjsd</p>       
        </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="my-form">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="validateForm()" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
              </div>    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>    
            </div> 
        </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div style="width:500px;heigth:350px;border:solid 1px brown">
                <h1>GOOGLE MAP HERE!</h1>
              </div>
             <!-- <img sytle="padding:0px 20px" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Miami+Downtown,Miami,FL&zoom=13&size=500x350&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7CMiami+Downtown,Miami,FL">                     -->
          </div>      
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding:10px 140px">
              <p id="msg-result"></p>
            <!-- display form result message here! -->
      </div>

    <!--
    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
    -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are updating the text in the field and then submitting to php (wiping out all of the fields since the page refreshes). You could set hidden elements to hold the values that you want to display so they post over to php and then you can just echo them where you want them to be. Another way of doing it would be to make an ajax call to a php to do your updating instead of posting back to the same page.

So with ajax you would do something like:

```
formSubmit()
{
  //do validation

  //do a jquery post to a php page
  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    //the url of the php page
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    //json object to sent to the authentication url
    data: '{"test": "info"}',
    success: function (result) {

    //update stuff
    }
  })
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, It executes the javascript first but then it refreshes the page (because the form gets submitted).

Comment: but when you decide to display your hidden fields your page gets refresh also, right?

Comment: @miatech No, with Ajax your page won't refresh. That is the special thing about it ;) it can submit your form (and execute the php code) without refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the form is submitted after the check. You must return the result (to cancel the submit if validateForm() is false):

```
onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

or prevent default:

```
onsubmit="return validateForm(event);"
```

with

```
function validateForm(event) {
    ...
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: ok "return false" seemed to fixed it, but does that mean that the php script will not execute?

Comment: Yes, either you use JS just for the check so you display the message with PHP, or you must use AJAX with the response from Nived. And do not forget: JS can be disabled easily, you must secure again the form in PHP.

Comment: right.. may be I didn't explain myself. what intend to do is to do validation with javascript before send it to php; however, if the javascript validation succeeded, I want to send it php, but I want the javascript to post the message at the end of page. Maybe this is done with php. But I'm trying to have the php script in a separate page. is it possible to post message at the buttom of form if you send to separate php script?

Comment: If you look at my answer you can see how a post to a php page (and getting back data) can be done without refreshing the page. (You may have to dig more into how ajax works but that's somewhat out of the scope of the question)

Comment: Yes, with AJAX as Nived has explained, you can also use an iframe but AJAX is a better approch.